# React with routes deployed with FastApi blocks fastapi endpoints

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, fastapi

I've a working example of serving create-react-app build with FastApi.

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static/static", html=True), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="static")

app.include_router(auth.router)
app.include_router(api.router)


@app.route("/{path:path}")
async def read_root(request: Request, path: str = None):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

React app routing is working, and sides that use get methods from backend work as well, but the post method that should return a token does not work and returns `405 error, method not allowed`.

i have tried doing things like these:
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/130#issuecomment-491379252
yet this doesn't help at all.

Comment: Have you specified CORS origins? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/

Comment: Yes i have specified it but it and the error seemed to be that i left one trailing slash "/" in the URL for getting the token. After removing it al is fine